# How do you obtain the Serial Killer challenge?

Tags: achievements, assassins-creed-revelations

In multiplayer mode, there is a challenge called *Serial Killer*, which seems quite easy to get. Its description is *Play a session with every Persona*.

I did that but the challenge didn't progress. Do I have to play with the persona from the upcoming DLC to unlock this one, or is it a session for each type of game?  Did some of you already see this challenge progressing?

Comment: I'm thoroughly annoyed by this stupid challenge. PC version again, we didn't get no freakin patch yet, we've been left out in the dark on _all_ "special events" (double XP weekend, holiday maps), lag is teeth-pullingly irritating and their DRM servers keep going down too often. I have _every_ customization unlocked, purchased and equipped on _all_ my personas. I played as _every single persona_ (at least) **twice** in a single sitting and _won_ each **twice**.  Still don't have the challenge yet.  I guess I'll have to wait for that patch to eventually arrive, I'm not getting this one ever. :(

Comment: Yay, they've finally patched the PC version... finally I can get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Jeff is right about Disguise. I played Brotherhood and that had the same challenge, and I completed it by just playing as each of the original characters(not any preorder or DLC characters). Doing that in Revelations though, doesn't work(as you say). The new DLC characters also aren't enough to get the challenge as I got them the other day, played them all and still haven't unlocked the first level of Serial Killer. All I can assume is that there's either some bug or glitch that needs taken care of, or that for some stupid reason, the Ottoman Doctor(the only character not in my list) is included in the characters needed to be played. My money is on a glitch or bug though, because although I don't have the doctor, I have played as him in team matches where the team leader had him in thier list, and that should have been enough. I've also heard that the new trophies that come with the character DLC aren't popping either(though I haven't confirmed that myself). If that's true, then I assume they'll release an update at some stage that hopefully fixes both issues. Serial Killer is a very easy challenge to get, so I'm not fussed as long as they take care of it eventually.

Also, I tried playing as evey character I have in my list after downloading the DLC(thinking it might have stared the count again) and that still had no effect.

The only other thing I think it could possibly be is that you have to play as every character in a single sitting, without signing out. I might try that next...

**Edit:**

Well I tried playing as every character in a single sitting last night and it didn't work. My new theory is that it might require having unlocked and purchased (with Abstergo credits) every character upgrade for weapons, visuals, taunts, stuns etc... and then to have played a session with every character. This would obviously take a lot of sessions, but luckily, I've played a lot, so I'm not too far away from trying it out.

All I need is about 300 credits worth of stuff for the Vanguard and everything for the Sentinal, which is probably about 1000-1200 credits worth, give or take. This will still take a while for me to check, maybe a few days, or a week, but I'll come back and post the result when I know. Unless of course the issue gets solved in the meantime. Knowing this game as I do, my money is still on a bug or glitch as the cause.

**2nd Edit:**

I got the first level of Serial Killer today. Though I'm still unsure of the exact cause of the original problem. The was an update yesterday which probably fixed it(and gave us "new" maps on sony network), but I did buy the last character upgrade today before the challenge popped, so I can't be sure. If someone gets the challenge without buying all upgrades for all characters, then perhaps they can answer to comfirm what's required.

I don't think the DLC characters count, for what it's worth, since I haven't been using them much.

Comment: Welcome! I've merged your two accounts. Please consider registering to avoid having to start over at 1 rep every time :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok just so that it is clearly said, in order to get this challenge, you *must* update the game to *at least* version **1.02**.  It was buggy and impossible to earn this challenge before the update.  The patch fixes the problem and makes it possible to earn.

With that being said, all you need to do is play at least 10 sessions up until the end in one sitting each using all of the original 10 personas in the game, it doesn't even matter if you didn't join the game in the beginning.  There could be three minutes left and if you wait til the end, it will still count.  You don't need to play as the unlockable personas (i.e., the renegade, DLC personas, the knight, etc.).  It doesn't have to be in the same game type and you don't necessarily need to win.  You only need to do this once for each of the three level badges.  So that's three total to get the gold badge.

Perhaps the fastest way to earn this challenge is to play a lot of **Corruption** games.  These games tend to go by fast.  Play as all the other personas you can choose in **Corruption**, then play a different game type so you can choose the **Count**.

I don't know for sure if you need to have all those personas customized, I have all customizations unlocked and equipped to the last customization option for all my personas so I couldn't really test it.  I don't think this would/should factor in to this challenge.

Comment: This is all based on my observations on my quest to get this challenge.  I have the gold badge for it.